# Tensor dot product with rank one tensor from vector

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to compute an inner product between tensors in numpy.

I have a vector $x$ of shape `(n,)` and a tensor $y$ of shape `d*(n,)` with `d > 1` and would like to compute $\langle y, x^{\otimes d} \rangle$. That is, I want to compute the sum

$$\langle y, x^{\otimes d} \rangle= \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_d\in\{1,\dots,n\}}y[i_1, \dots, i_d]x[i_1]\dots x[i_d].$$

A working implementation I have uses a function to first compute $x^{\otimes d}$ and then uses `np.tensordot`:

```
def d_fold_tensor_product(x, d) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Compute d-fold tensor product of a vector.
    """
    assert d > 1, "Tensor order must be bigger than 1."

    xd = np.tensordot(x, x, axes=0)
    for _ in range(d-2):
        xd = np.tensordot(xd, x, axes=0)

    return xd

n = 10
d = 4
x = np.random.random(n)
y = np.random.random(d * (n,))
result = np.tensordot(y, d_fold_tensor_product(x, d), axes=d)
```

Is there a more efficient and pythonic way? Perhaps without having to compute $x^{\otimes d}$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not much more efficient, but shorter:

```py
r=y
for i in range(d):
    r=r @ x
```